# Changing style in Frontend with commands from Backend Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, plugins

I am developing a custom wordpress plugin and I want to give the option to the users to change the Style of the contents that the plugin prints and I want to do that from the admin menu with Checkboxes.  I have created the checkboxes, now what I want is to make changes in the front-end CSS when I press the back-end Checkbox.
Right now I think I have a registering problem, since the checkbox does not stay Active after saving changes.
Code:

```
<div class="wrap vsuc-wrapper">
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php settings_errors() ?>
        <?php settings_fields('vsuc_option_group'); ?>
  <?php echo '<h3 class="header_admin">Viorel Stanciu User Counter Plugin</h3>'; ?>
        <label class="label_text" for="vsuc_field_eat">Text Label: (only for not logged in users)</label>
        <input name="vsuc_text_field" id="vsuc_field_eat" type="text" value=" <?php echo get_option('vsuc_text_field'); ?> "><br>
    <h3 class= "styleChoose"> Choose display style </h3>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vsuc_checkbox1" name="vsuc_checkbox1" value="style1">
    <label for="checkbox1"><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>/img/style1.PNG" class="style1"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="vsuc_checkbox2" value="style2">
    <label for="checkbox2"><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>/img/style2.png" class="style1"></label><br>
    <?php echo '<p class="shortcode"> Insert this shortcode where you want to display the plugin: [pagehits]';
     submit_button(); ?>
    </form>

function vsuc_register_settings() {
    register_setting('vsuc_option_group', 'vsuc_text_field');
    register_setting('vsuc_option_group', 'vsuc_checkbox1');
}
```

The option "vsuc text field" works perfectly and what I write stays in there but not for the checkboxes.

I would need from you a check if you can on this code and any idea for Changing CSS When the Checkbox is selected, what code should I use in my Js

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox inputs aren't being marked as [checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).

You'll need to output the `checked` output based on what the option value is.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  id="vsuc_checkbox1"
  name="vsuc_checkbox1"
  value="style1"
  <?php if (/** insert checked value logic here */) echo "checked"; ?>
/>
```

Comment: Hello, can you please be more explicit. You are saying I should write what I want to happen (Which is a javascript function right now) inside that If? You can update the answer or post another one since I saw you don't have 50 reputation for answering

Comment: @VSdev Judging by the code you've posted, there's nothing to mark the checkbox as enabled based on the data you have saved. A checkbox can be marked as checked by adding the `checked` attribute like so: `<input type="checkbox" checked />`. The code above just conditionally adds the attribute to your markup based on whatever conditions you need it to be checked.